# exists pagination in material angular or alternative?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In ng-bootstrap exists pagination, I looked at [`material.angular.io`](https://material.angular.io/components) and in github. But I have not seen anything similar, exists, any componente or alternative that is not documented?

Update:

*With alternative I mean that inside MD, use another component and modify its behavior, by some simple adjustment ect. or used another name instead of
pagination*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Materialise Pagination

http://materializecss.com/pagination.html